# Is there a way to generate a HTML form from a Draft-4 JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I make use of things like oneOf etc in my schema definitions. I'd like a library that will generate a HTML form from that.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few documentation generator tools listed on the bottom of this page: http://json-schema.org/implementations.html

You can try them out.

Answer (score 1):

Try bootprint-json-schema : https://github.com/bootprint/bootprint-json-schema.
Bootprint is a generic framework for generating HTML from JSON.